# How to make column contents as column names JTable - MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have the same data with different criteria, and want to display on JTable, can someone help me?
ex: I have data in table "alternative"

with ID = id01 (3 data)

first data "id01 with criteria1 = 01",

second data "id01 with criteria2 = 02".

I want to display in table with ID column, criteria1, criteria02 with value of id01,01,02. appear horizontally

Picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqdIf.jpg]

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Draw an ASCII picture showing the data in the table as you want it displayed.

Comment: here I demonstrated in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqdIf.jpg

Comment: We still don't have all the information needed to solve the problem. For example: 1) How many criteria are there, is it a fixed number or random number? 2) do all id's have all the criteria or a subset of the criteria?

Comment: in what format do you have the database values? a List<String[]> ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start with a `List<String[]>` such as

```
List<String[]> dataFromDatabase = new ArrayList<>();
dataFromDatabase.add(new String[] {"id01", "criteria1", "1"});
dataFromDatabase.add(new String[] {"id01", "criteria2", "2"});
dataFromDatabase.add(new String[] {"id01", "criteria3", "5"});
dataFromDatabase.add(new String[] {"id02", "criteria1", "6"});
dataFromDatabase.add(new String[] {"id02", "criteria2", "7"});
dataFromDatabase.add(new String[] {"id02", "criteria3", "10"});
```

You can run through it and store the data in the format you want in a Map:

```
Map<String, String[]> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for(String[] dataArray : dataFromDatabase) {
  String id = dataArray[0];
  String criteria = dataArray[1];
  String value = dataArray[2];

  String[] result = resultMap.getOrDefault(id, new String[3]);

  if("criteria1".equals(criteria))
    result[0] = value;
  else if("criteria2".equals(criteria))
    result[1] = value;
  else if("criteria3".equals(criteria))
    result[2] = value;

  resultMap.put(id, result);
}
```

You would end up with a Map like this:

```
{ "id01", ["1","2","5"] }
{ "id02", ["6","7","10"] }
```

I could refine the answer if you give more details.